# parse into another array contain xml child node using php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

currently, im having problem to parse xml node in array using condition where parse with `<mo>` as separator

this is my array(0)

```
Array([0] => <mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>);
```

i want to parse like this

```
Array[0] => <mi>x</mi>
Array[1] =><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>
Array[2]=><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>
```

this is my coding

```html
<?
$result(0)="<mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>";
$result1= new simplexml_load_string($result);
$arr_result=[];
foreach($result1 as $key => $value){
     $exp_key = explode('<', $key);
    if($key[0] == 'mo'){
         $arr_result[] = $value;
    }
print_r($arr_result);
}


if(isset($arr_result)){
    print_r($arr_result);
}
?>
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with XML seems excessive since what you really want is to pull out substrings of a string based on a delimiter.

Here is a working example. It works by finding the position of `<mo>` and cutting off that section, then searching for the next `<mo>` in the remain string.

```
<?php
$result(0)="<mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>";
$res = $result(0);
$arr_result=[];
while($pos = strpos($res, "<mo>", 1)) {
    $arr_result[] = substr($res, 0, $pos); // grab first match
    $res = substr($res, $pos); // grab the remaining string
}
$arr_result[] = $res; // add last chunk of string

print_r($arr_result);

?>
```

Your code above has several issues. 
First:

```
$result1= new simplexml_load_string($result); // simplexml_load_string() is a function not a class
```

Second:

`$key` and `$value` do not contain the '<' and '>' so, this part:
`$exp_key = explode('<', $key);` will never do anything and isn't needed.

Third:

If your code did work it would only return `array('+', '=')` because you are appending the data inside the `mo` element to the result array.

Comment: there are problem to call result as it in array form. how to call array by array

Comment: Could you please reword your question?

Comment: currently i have an array contain xml node as shown above is result(0). there are another array that i do not put here. im not sure either it store as string or xml in that array. 
$result = [];

foreach ($xml1->children() as $child) {
    if ($child->getName() === "mspace") {
        $result[++$counter] = [];
        continue;
    }
    $result[$counter][] = $child->saveXML();
}
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return implode("", $x);
}, $result);
print_r($result);
coding for &result

Comment: OK, so just make another string from the string in the first position of the array; `$res = $result(0);` and change the rest of the code accordingly.

Comment: if i wan to iterate more than one index? its work when i declare directly one index. but when i do loop for another index it seem does not work
coding below
for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) { 
    $res=$result[$i];

while($pos = strpos($res, "<mo>",1)) {
    $arr_result[] = substr($res, 0, $pos); // grab first match
    $res = substr($res, $pos); // grab the remaining string
}
}
$arr_result[] = $res; // add last chunk of string

print_r($arr_result);